# Open multiple files from different mainfolders and subfolders at once without opening folders using cmd

Tags: command-line, directory, subdirectory, multiple-select

I want to open multiple files, for examples excel b, excel g and excel k at once from different mainfolders and subfolders without opening folders using cmd, but I am not sure which mainfolder that containing that particular subfolder and excel files because there are dozens of mainfolders and hundreds of subfolders in each mainfolder.

The diagaram below is an example only. The real situation is I have to search particular containing subfolders from mainfolders and open it manually one by one.

folder 2024
|
|--- mainfolder 1
|          |
|          |--- subfolder a
|                   |-- file excel a
|          |--- subfolder b (maybe in mainfolder 1 or other mainfolder)
|                   |-- file excel b  ✓
|          |--- subfolder c
|                   |-- file excel c
|          |--- subfolder d
|                   |-- file excel d
|
|--- mainfolder 2
|          |
|          |--- subfolder e
|                   |-- file excel e
|          |--- subfolder f
|                   |-- file excel f
|          |--- subfolder g (maybe in mainfolder 2 or other mainfolder)
|                   |-- file excel g  ✓
|          |--- subfolder h
|                   |-- file excel h
|
|--- mainfolder 3
|          |
|          |--- subfolder i
|                   |-- file excel i
|          |--- subfolder j
|                   |-- file excel j
|          |--- subfolder k (maybe in mainfolder 3 or other mainfolder)
|                   |-- file excel k  ✓
|          |--- subfolder l
|                   |-- file excel l
|